# Solving the Neyman-Scott problem via Conditional MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimation, inference, conditional-probability, sufficient-statistics

In section 2.4 of the book Essential Statistical Inference by Boos and Stefanski, the authors discuss the idea conditional likelihoods and illustrate their usefulness by describing how they can be used to fix the Neyman-Scott problem.

In a general setting, given a parameter $\theta^T = (\gamma^T, \eta^T)^T$, where $\gamma$ is a parameter of interest, and $\eta$ is a nuisance parameter, they describe the following alternative to MLE based inference:

Find a one-to-one transformation of the data $Y$ to $(V,W)$ such that
$$
f_Y(y; \gamma, \eta)= f_{W,V}(w, v; \gamma, \eta) = 
f_{W|V}(w|v ; \gamma) f_V(v; \gamma, \eta).
$$
The density $f_{W|V}$ depends only on the parameter of interest, and a likelihood derived from it is called a conditional likelihood.

**Question 1** Is it obvious that maximizing $f_{W|V}$ is a good idea here? Ignoring $f_V$ seems strange since it is also a function of $\gamma$. Given i.i.d. data $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ from the model, it is not clear to me why the resulting conditional MLE (cMLE) estimator : $\hat{\gamma} \in \arg\max_{g} \sum_{i=1}^n \log f_{W|V}(w_i|v_i; g)$ is a reasonable one. Do we take it on faith this estimator will make $f_V$ large as well?

In the Neyman-Scott problem, we have $Y_{ij}, ~i=1,\dots,n, ~ j=1,2$ independent normal random variables with different means $\mu_i$ but the same variance. Here, $\eta = (\mu_1,\dots, \mu_n)^T$ and $\gamma = \sigma^2$.

The (full) MLE for $\sigma^2$ is not a consistent estimator. The authors propose to use conditional likelihood inference. To identify the transformations $V,W$ the idea is to use sufficiency. If we can identify sufficient statistics for the nuisance parameter $\eta$, assuming that $\theta$ is known, then conditioning on these sufficient statistics yields a distribution that is independent of the nuisance $\eta$ (whether or not $\theta$ is known).

To illustrate, we know $Y_{i1} + Y_{i2}=T_i$ is sufficient for $\mu_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$ in the $N(\mu_i,\sigma^2)$ family assuming $\sigma^2$ is known. Therefore, $Y|T$ does not depend on $\mu$. so we need to identify what $Y|T$ is. It is easy to show that $Y|T$ is a (degenerate) Gaussian, in that it does not have a density with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. The authors suggest that due to independence of $(Y_{i1}, Y_{i2}, T_i)$ over $i$, the required condtional ($Y|T$) can be readily determined from the conditional distribution of $Y_{i1}|T_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. The authors then find the conditional MLE based on the distribution of $Y_{i1}|T_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$. This latter distribution has a density, so the it is a straight forward MLE computation.

**Question 2** This is related to question 1. I was already confused about why using $Y|T$ for inference is a good idea a priori, but now we are using the distribution of $Y_1|T$. The idea of being able to determine $Y|T$ from $Y_1|T$ is fine, but why is it then reasonable to do MLE on $Y_1|T$?